# Saving and Loading PPO models across different Operating Systems

Tags: python, linux, macos, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I am training a PPO model on my `Mac OS`. I am using stable-baselines3 and Open AI's gym to train the model. I am running a genetic algorithm on a separate machine which runs `linux Zorin OS` to not overload my Mac so I can do other things. I am able to use the model fine on my mac, but when I am using it on the linux machine, the model gets stuck in the prediction method. Here is the code for saving the model on the `mac`:

```
model.save(f"/Users/.../Desktop/Coding/Personal/Python/QuantTrading/Code/DRL/stupidcode/models/BTCBITOmark1")
```

Here is how I am loading the model on the `linux Zorin` machine:

```
model = PPO.load(f'/home/michael/Desktop/Code/DRL/stupidcode/models/BTCBITOmark1.zip')
```

Here is how I am using predict on the `linux Zorin`:

```
self.model = model
observation = self.get_observation()
action = self.model.predict(observation, deterministic=True)[0]
```

I am using the same python version, and here is the result of `pip freeze` on the `mac`:

```
appdirs==1.4.4
appnope==0.1.3
asttokens==2.2.1
backcall==0.2.0
backtrader==1.9.78.123
beautifulsoup4==4.12.2
certifi==2023.5.7
charset-normalizer==3.2.0
cloudpickle==2.2.1
comm==0.1.3
contourpy==1.1.0
cycler==0.11.0
debugpy==1.6.7
decorator==5.1.1
empyrical==0.5.5
eventkit==1.0.0
executing==1.2.0
Farama-Notifications==0.0.4
filelock==3.12.2
fonttools==4.41.0
frozendict==2.3.8
gym==0.26.2
gym-notices==0.0.8
gymnasium==0.28.1
html5lib==1.1
ib-insync==0.9.86
ibapi==10.19.1
idna==3.4
ipykernel==6.24.0
ipython==8.14.0
jax-jumpy==1.0.0
jedi==0.18.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
joblib==1.3.1
jupyter_client==8.3.0
jupyter_core==5.3.1
kiwisolver==1.4.4
lxml==4.9.3
MarkupSafe==2.1.3
matplotlib==3.7.2
matplotlib-inline==0.1.6
mpmath==1.3.0
multitasking==0.0.11
nest-asyncio==1.5.6
networkx==3.1
numpy==1.25.1
packaging==23.1
pandas==2.0.2
pandas-datareader==0.10.0
parso==0.8.3
pexpect==4.8.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==10.0.0
platformdirs==3.9.1
prompt-toolkit==3.0.39
psutil==5.9.5
ptyprocess==0.7.0
pure-eval==0.2.2
pyfolio==0.9.2
pygad==3.1.0
Pygments==2.15.1
pyparsing==3.0.9
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2023.3
pyzmq==25.1.0
requests==2.31.0
scikit-learn==1.3.0
scipy==1.11.1
seaborn==0.12.2
Shimmy==1.1.0
six==1.16.0
sklearn==0.0.post7
soupsieve==2.4.1
stable-baselines3==2.0.0
stack-data==0.6.2
sympy==1.12
TA-Lib==0.4.27
threadpoolctl==3.2.0
torch==2.0.1
tornado==6.3.2
traitlets==5.9.0
typing_extensions==4.7.1
tzdata==2023.3
urllib3==2.0.4
wcwidth==0.2.6
webencodings==0.5.1
yfinance==0.2.25
```

and `pip freeze` from `linux Zorin`:

```
appdirs==1.4.4
asttokens==2.2.1
backcall==0.2.0
backtrader==1.9.78.123
beautifulsoup4==4.12.2
certifi==2023.5.7
charset-normalizer==3.2.0
cloudpickle==2.2.1
cmake==3.27.0
comm==0.1.3
contourpy==1.1.0
cycler==0.11.0
debugpy==1.6.7
decorator==5.1.1
empyrical==0.5.5
executing==1.2.0
Farama-Notifications==0.0.4
filelock==3.12.2
fonttools==4.41.0
frozendict==2.3.8
gym==0.26.2
gym-notices==0.0.8
gymnasium==0.28.1
html5lib==1.1
idna==3.4
ipykernel==6.24.0
ipython==8.14.0
jax-jumpy==1.0.0
jedi==0.18.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
joblib==1.3.1
jupyter_client==8.3.0
jupyter_core==5.3.1
kiwisolver==1.4.4
lit==16.0.6
lxml==4.9.3
MarkupSafe==2.1.3
matplotlib==3.7.2
matplotlib-inline==0.1.6
mpmath==1.3.0
multitasking==0.0.11
nest-asyncio==1.5.6
networkx==3.1
numpy==1.25.1
nvidia-cublas-cu11==11.10.3.66
nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu11==11.7.101
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu11==11.7.99
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu11==11.7.99
nvidia-cudnn-cu11==8.5.0.96
nvidia-cufft-cu11==10.9.0.58
nvidia-curand-cu11==10.2.10.91
nvidia-cusolver-cu11==11.4.0.1
nvidia-cusparse-cu11==11.7.4.91
nvidia-nccl-cu11==2.14.3
nvidia-nvtx-cu11==11.7.91
packaging==23.1
pandas==2.0.2
pandas-datareader==0.10.0
parso==0.8.3
pexpect==4.8.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==10.0.0
platformdirs==3.9.1
prompt-toolkit==3.0.39
psutil==5.9.5
ptyprocess==0.7.0
pure-eval==0.2.2
pyfolio==0.9.2
pygad==3.1.0
Pygments==2.15.1
pyparsing==3.0.9
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2023.3
pyzmq==25.1.0
requests==2.31.0
scikit-learn==1.3.0
scipy==1.11.1
seaborn==0.12.2
Shimmy==1.1.0
six==1.16.0
soupsieve==2.4.1
stable-baselines3==2.0.0
stack-data==0.6.2
standard-scaler==0.3
sympy==1.12
TA-Lib==0.4.27
threadpoolctl==3.2.0
torch==2.0.1
tornado==6.3.2
traitlets==5.9.0
triton==2.0.0
typing_extensions==4.7.1
tzdata==2023.3
urllib3==2.0.4
wcwidth==0.2.6
webencodings==0.5.1
yfinance==0.2.25
```

I cannot figure out why it works fine on the Mac but not on the Linux machine. I am assuming it has to do with the difference in operating systems but I am not sure why. **Please Help**

**Update** I forgot to mention that the Linux Machine is running on Intel Core I7 and the model was trained on my Mac that has the M2 Max Chip.

I have added the parameter `print_system_info = True` to the load function. Here is the results:

```
== CURRENT SYSTEM INFO ==
- OS: Linux-5.15.0-76-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.31 # 83~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 21 20:23:31 UTC 2023
- Python: 3.11.4
- Stable-Baselines3: 2.0.0
- PyTorch: 2.0.1+cu117
- GPU Enabled: False
- Numpy: 1.25.1
- Cloudpickle: 2.2.1
- Gymnasium: 0.28.1
- OpenAI Gym: 0.26.2

== SAVED MODEL SYSTEM INFO ==
- OS: macOS-12.5.1-arm64-arm-64bit Darwin Kernel Version 21.6.0: Wed Aug 10 14:28:23 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8020.141.5~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000
- Python: 3.11.4
- Stable-Baselines3: 2.0.0
- PyTorch: 2.0.1
- GPU Enabled: False
- Numpy: 1.25.1
- Cloudpickle: 2.2.1
- Gymnasium: 0.28.1
- OpenAI Gym: 0.26.2
```